# JSR-303 how to ignore validation on specific fields in a bean some of the time

Tags: bean-validation

I am validating a large bean.  It is based of a dynamic form page.  Some fields that are being validated are not visible on the form and hence empty or null.  But I don't want the invisible fields to be validated.  Sometimes they are visible and I want them to be validated, sometimes they are not visible and I don't want them to be validated.  I first took the approach of stripping these fields from the serialized form before submitting.  But it still validates the missing fields because they exist in the bean with validation tags.  What is the right way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach is using validation groups. You define different validation rules for different groups. Afterwards you can call the validator just for one of these groups or for a set of groups.

```
public class TestBean {

    @NotNull(groups= {Group1.class})
    @Size.List({
        @Size(min=1, groups= {Group1.class}),
        @Size(min=0, groups= {Group2.class})
    })
    private String test;
}

public interface Group1 { }
public interface Group2 { }
```

then you can call the validator for one or more of these groups

```
Validator validator = ....;
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(objectToValidate, Group1.class);
```

For more information about validating groups see [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups).

Comment: I am not sure how I would make use of groupings for this situation after reading your linked page.  I don't want asserts, I need to return to the page with the error next to the offending field.  Also, it is one bean.  Not bean extending bean extending bean.  And for many fields I prefer to use the default validators.  I don't want to write custom for every field.

Comment: I think groups is the right way to go. Groups are intended to select/group a bunch of constraints depending on certain use cases. There is no need for "bean extending bean" when using groups. The question is how you can target the right validation group in the validate call. This will depend on your integration technology and how you use Bean Validation.

Comment: The trouble I see with groups is the groups are different depending on what fields are visible on the page.  Also I want field level errors to display on the page.  I am exploring a way to pass an ignore list to the validator then if the field is in that list just pass validation.    If it is not in the list do its validation and pass fail appropriately.  That way the logic behind the decision to make a field visible or not is located in one spot not two spots.  which would make it hard to maintain.  The trick is to pass the list with every validation.  Along with the field to validate.