# Conditional Bean Validation of Superclass

Tags: java, bean-validation

Use-case: When adding/editing an address or setting a direct delivery address the form has the same fields. So it's good practice to use the address form class as a super class of the delivery form:

```java
public class AddressForm {
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    // ...
}

public class DeliveryForm extends AddressForm {
    public static enum ShippingType {
        DIRECT_SHIPPING,
        // ...
    }

    @NotNull
    private ShippingType shippingType;
    // ...
}
```

Is it possible to create a custom constraint (validator) at class level to set the condition whether the super class should be validated or not?

Such as:

```java
@ValidateSuperclassIf(field = "shippingType", value = "DIRECT_SHIPPING")
public class DeliveryForm extends AddressForm {
    // ...
}
```

How to implement the `javax.validation.ConstraintValidator<ValidateSuperclassIf, Object>.isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context)` method then?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that you want to have different validation rules for the 2 different forms based on the same classes?
Why not using validation groups for different validation rules in this case?
maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480489/jsr-303-how-to-ignore-validation-on-specific-fields-in-a-bean-some-of-the-time for validation groups

Comment: No. Same Validation but only validate the super class if a condition is fulfilled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a custom constraint (validator) at class
>   level to set the condition whether the super class should be validated
>   or not?

No, you cannot. There are not means in Bean Validation (the spec) nor in the reference implementation Hibernate Validator to do so.

There are some discussions to have the ability to skip super type constraints ([HV-548](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-548) and [BVAL-256](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/BVAL-256)), but that would just generally disable them, not add conditional (de-)activiation.

Comment: Then I have to manage my fields twice. Thanks for the Info and Links.